# Accessing instance variables in Ruby OOP

Tags: ruby, oop

I am learning Ruby OOP and have been faced with the following question.

> What could we add to the class below to access the instance variable
>   @volume?

```
class Cube
  def initialize(volume)
    @volume = volume
  end
end
```

My initial thought was to add `attr_reader :volume` to access the instance variable.

Instead the model answer suggests adding a new method as below.

```
def get_volume
  @volume
end
```

Why is this the preferred method?
Both methods would output 100 if `cube.volume` or `cube.get_volume` were called.

Comment: The resource you're learning this from is crap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_reader`. In general methods with `get_` prefix are rather avoided in Ruby community (in opposite to commonly seen in Java/C# code)

Comment: Yes, exactly as you thought.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dynamically created variable, then you can use `instance_vairable_get`, like below -

```
instance_variable_get("@volume")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is desired to get the variable `volume` ,I will suggest the use of `attr_reader :volume`. This creates a proxy method `volume` so no need to add( and later have to maintain) an extra method `get_volume` for this sole purpose.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader

Answer (score 0):

You should use **attr_reader :volume** instead of using get_volume method.
Stil attr_reader and your method get_volume both are functioning same.
Generally **get_** methods should be avoided in ruby.